# How do I get the parametric form solution of a linear system from reduced row-echelon form?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following system of equations:

```
x1 + 6x2 + 2x3 - 5x4 = 0
-x1 - 6x2 - x3 - 3x4 = 0
2x1 + 612x2 + 5x3 - 18x4 = 0
```

and I understand that it translated into the following matrix:

```
1       6     2     -5     0
-1     -6    -1     -3     0
2      12     5     -18    0
```

Finally, I understand how to use Gauss-Jordan elimination to change this to reduced row-echelon form:

```
1    6    0   11    0
0    0    1   -8    0
0    0    0    0    0
```

However, in an example solution that my instructor has prepared, this is then used to find the general solution in parametric form:

```
x1 = -6s - 11t
x2 = s
x3 = 8t
x4 = t
```

No intermediate steps are given. I can see that a similarity in the numbers, but I'm not sure exactly what to do.

It looks like arbitrary letter variables have been assigned to those columns which don't start any row with a one and then these variables are used to complete equations for the columns which do start rows. Is that all this is? Or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: (By the way, it looks like you have a typo: Your row-reduced matrix has a $1$ in the $(1,4)$-entry, but your general solution indicates you should have a $-11$ there.)

Comment: It was a couple of typos. The general solution is supposed to have a negative 11 and there's actually supposed to be a positive 11 where the one was. Sorry.

Comment: Okay, hah, and it looks like I made a typo too. All fine :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remember that augmented matrices correspond to systems of linear equations.  Once you've finished row-reducing, turn the row-reduced matrix back into a system of equations and solve for the variables in the pivot columns:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1  &  6 &   0  &  11 & | & 0 \\
0  &  0  &  1  & -8  & | & 0 \\
0  &  0  &  0  &  0  & | & 0\end{pmatrix} \longrightarrow 
\begin{cases}x_1 + 6x_2 + 11x_4 = 0 \\ 
x_3 -8x_4 = 0\end{cases}\longrightarrow \begin{cases}x_1 = -6x_2 - 11x_4 \\ x_3 = 8x_4.\end{cases}$$
The free variables $x_2,x_4$ are now parameters.  Once you specify them, you specify a single solution to the equation.  So subsitute $x_2 = s,x_4 = t$ and arrive at the parametrized form:
$$\begin{cases} 
x_1 = -6s - 11t\\
x_2 = s\\
x_3 = 8t\\
x_4 = t
 \end{cases}$$